# How to convert docx to xhtml

Tags: java, apache-poi, xhtml, docx4j, xdocreport

I am trying to find a solution to convert a docx file to XHTML.

I found xdocreport, which looks good, but I have some issues. (and I am new to xdocreport)

According to their documentations on github [here](https://github.com/opensagres/xdocreport/wiki/Converters) and [here](https://github.com/opensagres/xdocreport/wiki/XDocReport200): I should be able to convert with this code:

```
    String source = args[0];
    String dest = args[1];

    // 1) Create options DOCX to XHTML to select well converter form the registry
    Options options = Options.getFrom(DocumentKind.DOCX).to(ConverterTypeTo.XHTML);

    // 2) Get the converter from the registry
    IConverter converter = ConverterRegistry.getRegistry().getConverter(options);

    // 3) Convert DOCX to (x)html
    try {
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File(source));
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(dest));
        converter.convert(in, out, options);
    } catch (XDocConverterException | FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I am using these dependencies (tried different versions, like 2.0.2, 2.0.0, 1.0.6):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport</groupId>
        <artifactId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport.document.docx</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport</groupId>
        <artifactId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport.template.freemarker</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport</groupId>
        <artifactId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport.converter.docx.xwpf</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

My issues:

- The images are missing
- The background color is missing (all pages have a background color, which is not white and I have to convert this too)

How can I handle these issues?
(Or how can I convert docx to xhtml using Docx4j with formats/numbering/images?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert `*.docx` to `XHTML` using `XDocReport` and `apache poi`'s `XWPFDocument` as the source you will need `XHTMLOptions`. Those options are able having `ImageManager` to set the path for extracted images from `XWPFDocument`. Then `XHTMLConverter` is needed to convert.

Complete example:

```
import java.io.*;

//needed jars: xdocreport-2.0.2.jar, 
import fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.xhtml.XHTMLConverter;
import fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.xhtml.XHTMLOptions;
import fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.core.ImageManager;

//needed jars: all apache poi dependencies
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

public class DOCXToXHTMLXDocReport {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  String docPath = "./WordDocument.docx";

  String root = "./";
  String htmlPath = root + "WordDocument.html";

  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream(docPath));

  XHTMLOptions options = XHTMLOptions.create().setImageManager(new ImageManager(new File(root), "images"));

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(htmlPath);
  XHTMLConverter.getInstance().convert(document, out, options);

  out.close();      
  document.close();     
 
 }
}
```

This handles images properly.

But `XDocReport` is unable handling page background colors of `XWPFDocument` properly until now. It extracts and handles paragraph background colors but not page background colors.

Comment: Thank you, working nice :) I have 2 questions, What if there are text / images in the footer? How can I handle those? Is there a way to store the images inside of XHTML (So not using a folder with pictures, outside of the file?)

Comment: `XDocReport` does not handling headers and footers of `XWPFDocument` until now. And `XHTML` is hyper **text** markup. This is not embedding images. It links images via `IMG` elements: `<img src="images/image1.png" style="width:54.0pt;height:48.95pt;"/>`.